# How create an average of String value field in Dax/PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm a newbie in Dax and trying to use the function to group by a determinate field of the static worksheet where a need sum the values that are basically the same.

To solve this case, how could I create a new measure and use it to a stacked column chart?

The idea would be like that:

```
IF DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Block Partial" && DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Block Partial LL" 
    RETURN "Block Partial"

ELSIF
   DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Block Total" && DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Block Total LL"
    RETURN "Block Total"

ELSIF
   DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Canc. Service" && DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Single Cancel LL"
    RETURN "Cancel Service"

ELSIF   
    DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Unlock Partial" && DESCRIPTION_ACTION = "Unlock Total LL"
      RETURN "Unlock"

ELSE
    "UNKNOWN SCENARIO"
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and what the expected result should looks like.

Comment: @AgustinPalacios
I had put this code above, where I receive two descriptions of actions that perform the same operation on the system.
Therefore, on the worksheet, I intend to group by the same operation (that have name differents however do the same action) to return just one value it.